# Should android have a permissions tag relevant to only Android?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I browsed through the questions tagged `permissions`. I see some of them are related to Android, while others aren't.

Since permissions on Android are a different matters in respect with permissions in other fields, I think the use of a new tag (i.e. android-permissions) should be encouraged, and users with permission to retag should do this.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think it makes sense that if you have a question about Android permissions, you should tag it with "android" and "permissions", separately.  Mostly because it hurts my brain to imagine there being a million new tags like:

[android-permissions](/questions/tagged/android-permissions)
[sql-server-permissions](/questions/tagged/sql-server-permissions)
[file-system-permissions](/questions/tagged/file-system-permissions)
[thingadongdong-permissions](/questions/tagged/thingadongdong-permissions)

So, I think the current configuration is acceptable.  The main thing is, you have an Android question; people interested / skilled in that tag will see it because of the "android" tag.  "Permissions" is just a little extra information (which they will eventually get from reading the question).

<sub>Now...whether having a "permissions" tag is all that useful to begin with, I don't know (I can't imagine alot of people following the "permissions" tag).  But, that would be a topic for another question.</sub>

Comment: Permissions are pretty important in Android, especially minimizing the number you use

Comment: @BenBrocka That makes sense.  I just don't think it warrants another tag.  It seems like too much overlap, and it sets a bad precedent for creating new tags.  This is just my opinion though.

Comment: I don't think it needs a new tag beyond the combo of Android and Permissions personally...permissions aren't language agnostic so I think it's implicitly clear that permissions depends on a language tag.

Comment: @BenBrocka Right.  It would be like having a tag for sorting algorithms in different languages ([android-sorting], [C#-sorting], [java-sorting]).  It turns into something unweildy and unnecessary.